# Fubini's theorem and $\sigma$-finiteness?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reviewing my analysis notes, and I am really confused about what is meant by $\sigma$-finiteness being a hidden hypothesis of Fubini's theorem.

Here is Fubini's theorem as was stated to me:

> Suppose $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $(Y, \tau, \nu)$ are complete measure spaces.  Consider the complete product measure space $(X \times Y, \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}, \lambda)$.  If $f \in L^{1}(d\lambda)$, then $\int \limits_{X\times Y} f d\lambda = \int \limits_{X} \left [ \int \limits_{Y} f d\nu \right ] d\mu$.

I was also told that a measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ being $\sigma$-finite is equivalent to there existing $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$ such that $f > 0$.  This equivalence was easy to prove.

I can't wrap my head around where $\sigma$-finiteness is "hiding" in this theorem (although my professor mentioned something about the ability to find a sequence of simple functions $s_{n}$ which is monotonic increasing and converges to our non-negative function $f$ -- this was a necessary step in our proof).  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: According to Wikipedia for non $\sigma$-finite measure spaces Fubini's theorem is still true for the right choice of product measure.  So I don't know what could be meant by the phrase "hidden hypothesis".  Depending on the definition of your product measure (it is not unique when the spaces aren't $\sigma$-finite) the theorem as stated may not even be true.

Comment: @PhoemueX link is broken, can you fix it?

Comment: I found this paper (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-42/issue-1/A-remark-on-Tonellis-theorem-on-integration-in-product-spaces/pjm/1102968019.full) to be quite instructive.

Comment: @Peanut: Done...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Professor was probably talking about Tonelli's Theorem in regard to $\sigma$-finiteness.

If $f \in L^{1}(\mu\times\nu)$, then Fubini's theorem holds, regardless of $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$, $\nu$ or not. Of course all of the measures must be complete, including the product measure. The way this is proved is by reducing to the case of positive $f$ because the positive $f_{+}$ and negative parts have finite integrals. That allows you to approximate $f_{+}$, for example, by a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative simple functions $\{\varphi_{n}\}$ converging upward to $f_{+}$ with the property that each is supported on a set of finite measure. This approximation is a critical part of the standard proof.

Tonelli's Theorem is a generalization of Fubini's Theorem for the case of positive functions $f$, where the assumption of integrability of $f$ is dropped; that is, you allow for the possibility that $\int f\,d(\mu\times\nu) = \infty$. You still get the same conclusion as Fubini's Theorem for such a case, provided you assume that the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite. By adding this assumption of $\sigma$-finiteness, you are still able to get the existence of $\{\varphi_{n}\}$ as above which are once again supported on sets of finite measure. So the proof of Fubini's Theorem goes through, even without assuming $f$ has a finite integral. However, in this case, I think you can see the need for $\sigma$-finiteness, whereas in Fubini's Theorem, it was only necessary to assume $\int |f|\,d(\mu\times \nu) < \infty$ in order to get the desired approximation.

Comment: I understand what you mean.  But why does $\sigma$-finiteness of a measure imply that we can find simple functions converging up to a measurable function?  I have a proof that actually constructs simple functions converging to the non-negative real-valued measurable function in question, but I can't see where $\sigma$-finiteness is assumed in that construction.  Do you know why?  By the way, thanks for your answer!

Comment: The issue isn't getting a sequence of functions converging upward to $f$. It's getting functions, each of which is supported on a set of finite measure, to do the job. Clearly any such sequence cannot approach $f$ unless $f$ is supported on a $\sigma$-finite set.

Comment: Hm, that's not the construction that I was taught.  Here is the construction of a sequence of nonnegative simple functions that converges up to a nonnegative measurable function $f$ (could take the value $\infty$): for $j = 0, 1, \cdots, (n-1)2^{n}$, let $s_{n} = \begin{cases} j2^{-n} & j2^{-n} \leq f(x) < j2^{-n} + 1 \\ n & f(x) \geq n  \end{cases}$

Comment: I am still new to this material and I am trying to digest it.  The statement "clearly any such sequence cannot approach $f$ unless $f$ is supported on a $\sigma$-finite set" does not make sense to me.  I know that the support of a function is the set of values where the function takes a non-zero value, but I'm not able to tie everything together.

Comment: If each $\varphi_{n} \ge 0$ is supported on a finite-measure set, and if $\varphi_{n}\uparrow f$, then $f$ is supported on $\cup_{n}\mbox{supp}(\varphi_{n})$. Isn't that clear?

Comment: So you are saying if the set of values where $\phi_{n}$ is non-zero has finite measure, and the sequence is increasing and converges, then of course the limit is non-zero on the union of the support of the simple functions and so it is $\sigma$-finite.  But that doesn't mean the space we are working in is necessarily $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: If $f$ is absolutely integrable, then such a sequence exists, regardless of whether or not the underlying space is separable. Finite integral imposes that. But you don't want to impose integrability for $f \ge 0$ (Tonelli's Theorem.) That's why you need the additional assumption of having an underlying $\sigma$-finite measure space for that case. But Fubinit's Theorem doesn't require $\sigma$-finite for the underlying space because you assume the $f$ is in $L^{1}$.

Comment: Ok, I think I am understanding what you are saying.  The last thing I am confused about is why such a sequence exists if $f$ is absolutely integrable regardless of the $\sigma$-finiteness of the underlying space.  Is it because of the construction of my simple functions? P.S. Sorry for needing my hand to be held.

Comment: Because of the decomposition that is familiar to you. You can see that each set in your decomposition has finite measure, due to the fact that $f \in L^{1}$.

Comment: Ok, I will keep thinking about it.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: These issues are anything but simple in general. For example, suppose $f \ge 0$ is defined on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and that the iterated integrals (either direction first) exist and are well-defined using ordinary Lebesgue measure, but do not assume $f$ is jointly measurable. The question of whether or not the iterated integrals must be equal is BEYOND STANDARD MATHEMATICS. The question has no answer. That is, the question is independent of the standard ZFC axiomatic system for set theory! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-measurable_functions

Comment: Wow!  That's not an expected outcome from my point of view.  Now I don't feel so bad that it's taking me a while to understand this.  By the way, for any future users that stumble on this question, my sequence of simple functions was wrong.  It should have been: $j = 0, 1, \cdots, 2^{n}n - 1$, and $s_{n} = \begin{cases} j2^{-n} & j2^{-n} \leq f(x) < (j + 1)2^{-n} \\ n & f(x) \geq n \\  \end{cases}$

Comment: I would like to mention the counterexample here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-maximal_product_measures, which shows that one has to take the "right" product measure in the non-sigma-finite case. If one does, then your proof can be used to reduce the problem to the sigma-finite case, because each set of finite measure for the "maximal" product measure is contained in a countable union of a product of sets of finite measure, so we can apply the sigma-finite case to suitable restricted factor-measures. For a non-max. choice, this can fail!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question in the hopes that it may help someone else out there.  It will help me when I refer back to this page.

Here is the idea:  We can construct a sequence of simple functions $s_{n}$ which is monotonically increasing and converges to a non-negative measurable function $f$ (I discussed the usual construction in a comment on the other answer to this question).  This is true for any non-negative measurable function $f$.  The thing is, we don't necessarily know that the measure of the sets where each $s_{n}$ takes a non-zero, finite value is finite.  We could have that the measure of the set where $s_{n}$ takes the value $2$, for example, is $\infty$.  This could be true for all of the simple functions $s_{n}$, and so it would consequently be true for $f$.  (Here, $f$ has codomain $[0,\infty]$.)

So, when we assume that $f \in L^{1}(d\lambda)$, that means $\int \limits_{Z} |f| \,d\lambda < \infty$, and since $|f| = f$ because $f$ is non-negative, then we have $f < \infty$ a.e. d$\lambda$.  Since $s_{n} \leq f$ for all $n$, then for each $n$, $s_{n}$ can only take the value $\infty$ on a set of measure $0$.  Furthermore, by the monotonicity of the integral ($\int \limits_{Z} s \,d\lambda \leq \int \limits_{Z} f \,d\lambda < \infty$), since the integral of the simple function is finite, the sets where it takes those non-zero values will have finite measure.  So if $f \in L^{1}(d\lambda)$ and it is non-negative, then our usual construction of a sequence of simple functions will work, because the simple functions we construct have the property that the measures of the sets where they take non-zero values are finite, since their integral is finite (and the simple functions are finite almost everywhere).

Now, if we are not in $L^{1}(d\lambda)$, then $f$ could have integral $\infty$.  This is a problem, because the usual construction of the sequence of simple functions does not necessarily have that the measure of sets where the function takes non-zero values is finite.  The sequence of simple functions could have integral $\infty$ by having the measure of a set where they take a non-zero value be infinite.  Then we can't run through the proof of Fubini's theorem, which depended on this property, to prove Tonelli's theorem.  But assuming the space is $\sigma$-finite helps us, because we *can* construct a sequence of simple functions converging up to $f$ which have the desired property.  Just use $\sigma$-finiteness.  Write the space $Z = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_{n}$ with $\lambda(E_{n}) < \infty$ and $E_{n} \subseteq E_{n + 1}$.  Then $\chi_{E_{n}} \leq \chi_{E_{n + 1}}$, and since with our usual construction, $s_{n} \leq s_{n + 1}$, then $\{ s_{n} \chi_{E_{n}} \}$ is a sequence of simple functions that is increasing monotonically and converges up to $f$.  Then we can run through the regular proof of Fubini's theorem to prove Tonelli's theorem.