# Fubini's theorem for complete $\sigma$-algebras vs. non-complete $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $(Y, \tau, \nu)$ are both complete measure spaces.  Consider the following two measure spaces: $(X \times Y, \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}, \mu \times \nu)$ and $(X \times Y, \Sigma \times \tau, \mu \times \nu)$.

I know Fubini's theorem for the complete $\sigma$-algebra $\overline{\Sigma \times \tau}$:

> If $f \in L^{1}(d\mu \times d\nu)$, then:
>
> 1. The maps $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ are in $L^{1}(d\nu)$ for almost all $x$
> 2. The map $x \mapsto \int \limits_{Y} f(x,y) \,d\nu$ is in $L^{1}(d\mu)$
> 3. $\int \limits_{X \times Y} f(x,y) \,d(\mu \times \nu) = \int \limits_{X} \left [ \int \limits_{Y} f(x,y) \,d\nu \right ] \,d\mu$

**My first question:** in statement 1, I believe we also have that the maps are measurable for almost all $x$.  Then the map in 2 can only exist almost everywhere, so shouldn't it equal an $L^{1}(d\mu)$ function almost everywhere, rather than being in $L^{1}(d\mu)$ itself?

**My second question:**  What is different between Fubini's theorem above for $\overline{\Sigma \times \tau}$ and Fubini's theorem applied to $\Sigma \times \tau$?  I know that when we are dealing with $\Sigma \times \tau$, we have that the maps $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ are measurable for all $x$, not just almost everywhere, but aside from this, I don't know what else is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statement 2 means that the function defined by $\int_Y f(x,y) \, d\nu$ if the integral exists and arbitrary elsewhere is in $L^1(\mu)$.

By abuse of notation/language, this is written as "$x \mapsto \int_Y f(x,y) \,d\nu$ is in $L^1(\mu)$".

In the non-complete case, one has to define the function as $0$ (or any other fixed(!) value) if the integral does not exist, otherwise measurability may fail.

Regarding the statements that you posted, that is basically the only difference. It is true that the map $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is now measurable for **all** $x$, but it does **not** have to be integrable for all $x$ as the example

$$
f(x,y) = \chi_{\{0\} \times \Bbb{R}} (x,y)
$$

shows (with $\mu = \nu = \text{Lebesgue measure}$).

Comment: So does it really matter to have two different versions of Fubini's theorem?  They are essentially the same thing. except that in the beginning we can say the first map is measurable for all $x$.  But so what?  It doesn't really affect anything else.

Comment: Yes, the second version (for the completion) is actually **stronger**, because it tells you that even if $f$ is only measurable with respect to the **completion** of the product $\sigma$-Algebra (this is a weaker requirement than being measurable w.r.t. the product $\sigma$-algebra), then Fubini's theorem still holds.

Comment: @user46944: What I said in my last comment is true, but there is one essential difference in the prerequisites of the two versions I forgot to mention. For the version you posted, $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and the other measure space have to be **complete**. For the usual Fubini theorem, (where we take the product sigma-algebra instead of its completion) they need **not** be. Sometimes it is more advantageous to consider non-complete measure spaces. For example Borel sets have the advantage that $f\circ g$ is Borel-measurable if $f,g$ are. For Lebesgue-measurability, this is not so.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm having trouble understanding why if the two underlying spaces are not complete, Fubini's theorem would still hold.  I remember in proving Fubini's theorem for characteristic functions of sets in $\Sigma \times \tau$ with finite measure, we used the completeness of the underlying spaces.  So it seems to me that Fubini's theorem would not hold if the underlying spaces are not complete (or at least, I wouldn't know how to prove it).

Comment: How does your proof work? Normally, it goes as follows: First assume that both measure spaces are of finite measure. Then show that the class of all sets $M \in \Sigma \times \tau $for which $x \mapsto \nu(M_x)$ is measurable with $(\mu \times \nu)(M) = \int \nu(M_x) \, d\mu$ is a monotone class containing the "rectangle" sets. Use this to conclude that this holds for all $M \in \Sigma\times \tau$. It is then not hard to transition to $\sigma$-finite measures. Now, every $f \in L^1(\mu \times\nu)$ vanishes outside a countable union of "rectangles" of finite measure, so that this case suffices.

Comment: @user46944: See also this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887491/fubinis-theorem-and-sigma-finiteness?rq=1 including my comments on the question and on the answer. There are some subtleties regarding $\sigma$-finiteness as long as one is not only interested in the "Fubini" part of the theorem, but also in the "Tonelli" part, which states that finiteness of $\int \int |f(x,y)| \,d\mu \, d\nu$ already implies $f \in L^1(\mu\times\nu)$ (if $f$ is measurable with respect to $\Sigma \times \tau$).

Comment: The version I learned proved the statement in this way: First, in $\overline{\Sigma \times \tau}$, it was proved for $A$ that can be written as a countable intersection of countable unions of pairwise disjoint measurable rectangles (with the measure of $A$ finite).  Then we used the fact that any $E \in \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}$ can be approximated by the sets $A$ to prove that $E_{x} \in \tau$ a.e. $d\mu(x)$.  To prove this, we needed the underlying spaces to each be complete.

Comment: By the way, the question you linked to was a previous question that I asked.  I guess I am still having trouble with this theorem since I am still asking questions about it.  It's hard for me to consider all of these different scenarios for Fubini's theorem since I am still a beginner. :(