# Fubini on non-$\sigma$-finite, non-complete measure spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ are measure spaces (not assumed to be $\sigma$-finite or complete).
Define $\mathcal R$ to consist of all rectangles in $X \times Y$ of the form $A \times B$, where $A \in \mathcal A$ and $B \in \mathcal B$.
Define the premeasure $\lambda$ on $\mathcal R$ by $\lambda(A \times B) = \mu(A) \; \nu(B)$, where we assume $0 \cdot \infty = 0$.
Let $\mu \otimes \nu$ be the Carathéodory extension of $\lambda$ to a particular $\sigma$-algebra in $X \times Y$.
Let $\mathcal A \times \mathcal B$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra in $X \times Y$ containing $\mathcal R$.
Let $\mu \times \nu$ be the restriction of $\mu \otimes \nu$ to $\mathcal A \times \mathcal B$.
(We mention in passing that $\mu \otimes \nu$ is complete, but $\mu \times \nu$ may not be.)
It seems to be well-known that if $f$ is integrable with respect to $\mu \times \nu$, then Fubini holds:
$\int f \; d(\mu \times \nu) = \iint f  \; d\mu \; d\nu = \iint f \; d\nu \; d\mu$.
I believe I know how to prove this, but my question is this: 
Can someone refer me to a book, article, or website which presents a detailed proof?

Comment: This (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887491/fubinis-theorem-and-sigma-finiteness) could be helpful.

Comment: The paper <http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102968019> referenced in the above SE question (887491) does provide an indication of proof, depending on both Halmos and Royden. Does anyone know of a self-contained treatment?

Comment: Correct reference: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102968019